# what is the exact type of a Flask session

Tags: python-3.x, flask

In Pycharm, I would like to set the type of a Flask session parameter in a function like :

```
from flask import what ?

def my_function(self,session: what ?, ...)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the name of the class try

```
instance.__class__.__name__
```

If you want to see the type

```
type(instance)
```

if you want to get attributes of the instance

```
dir(instance)
```

Comment: Yes of course! I forgot to think to this simple solution. Thanks.